# Не могу задать TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В классе привязанному к layout есть функция

```
public void Result(String string){
    text1.setText(string);
}
```

Ей передается строка, но textiew не меняется, а выдается ошибка

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Иницилизация:

```
TextView text1;
```

и в `oncreate`

```
text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: text1 верно инициализировали?

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych добавил в вопросе уточнение

Comment: напишити мне на почту данные для подключениея через теам вивер. посмотрю на ваш код. martsinkevych@gmail.com

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков, где вызываете метод ваш?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в asynctask в onpostexecute

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков, а вы уверены, что в разметке есть у вас текстовое поле с таким ID? Ошибка может быть в 42 местах. Если вы не можете локализовать - выкладывайте весь код .

Comment: уверен, потому что в oncreate сделал `text1.setText();` и все сработало